# Can a template function taking class object instantiate that object with it's constructors arguments?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, initializer-list

Let's say I have a template function taking a class object:

```
template<class T>
void Foo(T obj);
```

and a class definition as follows:

```
class Bar 
{
public:
    Bar(int a, bool b): _a(a), _b(b) {}
private:
    int _a;
    bool _b;
};
```

Is there a way to make the following code compile?

```
Foo<Bar>(5,false);
Foo<Bar>({5,false}); // i know this works, just wondering if i can remove the brackets somehow.
```

Comment: `Foo` takes a single argument and in `Foo<Bar>(5,false);` you're passing two arguments.

Comment: Seems like a good case for a variadic template

Comment: @john You can forward the arguments, but only in the function body. It needs either another function, or some specialization where the arguments can be forwarded

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with variadic templates and forwarding, and has many standard examples, like `std::make_unique`.

In your case it would be:

```
template<class T, class ...Args>
void Foo(Args &&...args)
{
    T obj { std::forward<Args>(args)... };
    // use obj
}
```